# MVC Custom Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm new to MVC.  I'm having trouble trying to accomplish having a route setup in the following manner:

```
System/{systemName}/{action}
```

Where systemName is dynamic and does not have a "static" method that it calls. i.e.

`http://sitename.com/Systems/`**`LivingRoom`**`/View`

I want the above URL to call a method such as,

```
public void RouteSystem(string systemName, string action)
{
  // perform redirection here.
}
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: System != Systems.  Is that the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Systems_Default",
    "System/{systemName}/{action}",
    new { controller="System", action = "RouteSystem", systemName="" }
);
```

Should route your request as you specified.

Note that with the above route, your Url should be:

```
http://sitename.com/System/LivingRoom/View
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I used the following route.

```
       routes.MapRoute(
            "BlogSpecific",                                              // Route name
            "{blogSubFolder}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { blogSubFolder = "", controller = "", action = "", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

blogSubFolder just gets passed to my controller actions as a parameter.  Controller and action all work just as they usually do.  Just swap out blogSubfolder with your "System" paramter and that will hopefully work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you intend to route to a controller based on the system name. If that is correct then you would simply need this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Systems",
                "Systems/{controller}/{action}"
                new{controller = "YourDEFAULTController", action = "YourDEFAULTAction"});
```

Please note that the third line only sets the default values specified if they are NOT included in the url.

Given the route above, MVC would route this:

http://sitename.com/Systems/LivingRoom/View

to the View action method on the LivingRoom controller. However this:

http://sitename.com/Systems/LivingRoom

would route to the YourDEFAULTAction method on the LivingRoom controller.